# join CompletableFuture vs synchronous method

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, completable-future

Having:

```
String getData(String key){
    // Slow operation
}

CompletableFuture<String> getDataAsync(String key){
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getData(key));
}
```

What is the difference between the following?

**a)**

```
keyStream.map(key -> getData(key));
```

**b)**

```
keyStream.map(key -> getDataAsync(key).join());
```

Is there any advantage to use async in this case?

Comment: Please explain your question a bit more.

Comment: There's no difference: `join()` will block until a result is available.

Answer (score 1):

**IF** the stream in both approach a and b are sequentially. there is no different between them, and you should avoiding use it. because you just run the `getData` in the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` & join the the `map` method until `getData` was completed.

**IF** the stream in both approach a and b are parallelism. there is no different between them too, and you also should avoiding use it. because a parallel stream is already using the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` for its operations.

Answer (score 0):

Usage Async here in your example will not make difference as you are calling join with that so join is blocking call and Async will no more be ASync